# Pause at the end of `scp` transfer: from OSX or FreeBSD to Ubuntu

Tags: scp

I make binary images for the releases of a freeware program for about seven platforms, with the help of VirtualBox images.  The images are copied via `scp` to an Unbuntu system.

I've noticed that from some operating systems, notably OS X (10.7.3) and FreeBSD 9.0, there is an annoying pause at the end of `scp` transfer before the program terminates and control of the tty returns to the shell.

The transfer are successful (and I think that `scp` can be killed at the point where it is hanging; it makes no difference to the file integrity any more).

From other operating systems, like Solaris 10 or Debian 5, the transfer is fast and terminates instantly when it reaches 100%.

The transfers are all either between VM's on the same host, or over a wired LAN (100 mb/s) which has next to no traffic; no Wi-Fi or WAN is involved.

Has anyone experienced this and drilled down to the root cause?

Comment: I just reproduced it minutes ago and measured the pause: 12 seconds! This upload is my last step before I suspend the virtual machine to free up memory, so it is annoying.

Comment: Did you try using `strace` (or equivalent) to see what scp is doing during that time?

Comment: @ChrisDown Nope. Maybe someone has root-caused this already, so I don't want to waste time duplicating the effort. I can't be the first person to `scp` a file from Mac OS to Linux, and notice a pause.

Comment: That was really a request phrased as a question. If you can't be bothered to spend even a little time trying to debug your problem, I don't see why others should feel motivated to.

Comment: @ChrisDown I'm only using those platforms to port my program; not for day to day use. I made over 1500 commits in the trunk, over five years, culminating in 28000 LOC. I do not lack motivation! But I can't solve every little distracting annoyance that comes my way. That's why it's good to have a site like this. Maybe someone has already figured this out, but hasn't shared the solution. This must be known; it's not some corner case in some obscure program!